# Install Redis on Plesk Onyx (CentOS) and update PhpRedis

Tags: php, wordpress, redis, phpredis, plesk-onyx

Log in to the command line via SSH as the ROOT user and run the following commands line-by-line.

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
yum install tcl wget
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable/
make distclean
make
make test
make install
cd utils/
./install_server.sh
```

This will allow REDIS to use more memory than it has been allocated by Plesk if required

```
echo "vm.overcommit_memory = 1" >>  /etc/sysctl.conf  && sysctl  -p
```

Disable transparant_hugepage

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

Start and test your Redis service

```
systemctl start redis_6379
systemctl status redis_6379
```

[(credits)](https://ontwerps.nl/install-redis-with-plesk-onyx)

Check if redis is working (should reply with `PONG`)

```
redis-cli ping
```

Configure Redis to bind only on localhost for obvious security reasons by editing /etc/redis/6379.conf, uncommenting line 57 (bind 127.0.0.1 ::1)

```
vi /etc/redis/6379.conf
(edit and save)
systemctl restart redis_6379
```

Install EPEL (this is for CentOS 7, do `hostnamectl` to verify your version) then php-pecl-redis

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum install php-pecl-redis
```

Update PECL channels

```
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
```

Install php-devel package for your desired PHP version (here I am going with PHP 7.2)

```
yum install plesk-php72-devel
```

Finally install redis in PHP

```
/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/pecl install redis
```

Plesk should already have "extension=redis.so" enabled inside /etc/php.d/redis.ini

You can start using redis with phpredis!

Now, if you use WordPress with the plugin [Redis Object Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redis-cache/) you should see in diagnostic that you are using at least PhpRedis (v5.0.2) instead of the obsolete v.3 coming with default Plesk!

Enjoy

Comment: In addition to the disabling of transparent_hugepages you should add the same code into your /etc/rc.local

Comment: Also if you got here you should be voting for this to have a newer version of phpredis included by default:
https://plesk.uservoice.com/forums/184549-feature-suggestions/suggestions/40345246-update-phpredis-to-a-newer-version